# Using iCloud on Leopard with iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, leopard, icloud

I am on Leopard 10.5.8 (my MacBook is too old to upgrade to Snow Leopard) on itunes 10.5, and on iPhone 4 (iOS 5.0).

I have a MobileMe account.

My iPhone shows iCloud is available in the settings but I don't think I have signed up yet. Should I/can I move my MobileMe to iCloud and still be able to sync my phone to my mac? Or should I wait till I upgrade my mac to a newer version before next June.

Comment: what mac is it? There is an easy trick i read about to modify ur Lion installer to accept any intel mac

Comment: All MacBooks can run Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3):

If you migrate to iCloud now, you

- get all the iCloud benefits on the iPhone
- can still access your mail from your Mac ([HT4864](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864))
- you *should* still be able to share calendars and contacts (see [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1176780) but I haven't had a need to test this yet). This may actually be unsupported by Apple but if everything else fails you could always set up a Google Calendar for this.
- will loose all the other MobileMe benefits (like bookmark, pref, keychain syncing, gallery, iDisk etc.)
- will still be able to sync the content of your iPhone with your Mac

Comment: If it is useful for you, I wouldn't mind an upvote or an accept :-)

Comment: I can confirm that you can sync calendars, Mail, and Contacts.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but I thought if you hadn't upgraded to iCloud by now you can't at all, the account will no longer be available for iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Leopard, then I do not believe you can get iCloud. I have both a PowerPC Mac Pro and an Intel MacBook Pro. For my PowerPC Mac the highest OS I can go is Leopard, and I do not see any option for iCloud for it. If there is, I would really like to use it, but I've searched and haven't found anything yet. MobileMe will be discontinued sometime in June or July 2012, hence, all PowerPC Macs will be without MobileMe or iCloud. They're being left behind.

To answer your other question, Apple is offering upgrades to iCloud, and you will not lose any of your data. You can keep your @me.com email address (iCloud uses the same @me.com address anyway, even if you're new). I have even been able to keep my @mac.com address from several years ago, back when it was dot-Mac (.mac). I believe you can upgrade through the iPhone or on any web browser (probably most convenient anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Apple Mail for IMAP.

IMAP (Incoming Mail Server) information:

```
Server name: imap.mail.me.com
SSL Required: Yes
Port: 993
Username: example@me.com (use your @me.com address from your iCloud account)
Password: Your iCloud password
SMTP (outgoing mail server) information:
Server name: smtp.mail.me.com
TLS Required: Yes
Port: 587
SMTP Authentication Required: Yes
Username: example@me.com (use your @me.com address from your iCloud account)
Password: Your iCloud password
```